# Webcam / Microphone Detection

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash, camera, microphone

I would like to build a page that detects whether a user's camera / microphone is working similar to this: http://www.tokbox.com/user-diagnostic/

I just need guidance on where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi,I need to implement just the same as that you wanted,so Could you please help me on how to go about it,I am actually new to action script 3.0/flash.Thanks

Comment: @SumodhNair Please see the answer I posted.

Comment: 1+ for a hilarious user name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up building my own thing.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

I detected the camera number and the microphone number and pass it back to Javascript using ExternalInterface.

Works like a charm.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could share a sample code on how to proceed,I am confused between the calling being made in between as and js.

Comment: Yeah, just simply use this:                 ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", input.text);

Then in your Javascript have a function called sendToJavascript(text).

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback,was able to do so with externalInterface.As it turns out the problem was I wasnt running my code with security disabled,hence I wasnt able to call javascript via actionscript.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin can give you a list of available webcams the user has:

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

If `webcam.getCameraList().length == 0` then you'll know they don't have a webcam.

Answer (score 1):

In flash u can use

```
 var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
if (cam == null) 
{ 
    trace("User has no cameras installed."); 
} 
else 
{ 
    trace("User has at least 1 camera installed."); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @gyandas.kewat. Unfortunately, there is just no simple Has Mic? Yes / No; Has Cam? Yes / No tool so I just created one myself.

To extend this, I needed to use ExternalInterface, Camera, and Microphone classes for Actionscript 3 / Flash , and I sent my variables (cam, mic) from the Flash file to Javascript using ExternalInterface class.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @OneSneakyMofo : Hi,I need to implement just the same as that you wanted,so Could you please help me on how to go about it,I am actually new to action script 3.0/flash.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This.. to get access of webcam

```
$(function(){
    //initialize camera in browser
$("#camera").webcam({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            mode: "callback",
            swffile: "jscam_canvas_only.swf",
            onTick: function() {},
            onSave: function() {},
            onCapture: function() {},
            debug: function() {},
            onLoad: function() {}
        }); 
});

var test;
        test = function(){
            var tester = false;
            //try catch block for tight binding
            try{
                //condition if length is 0 or undefined
                if(webcam.getCameraList().length == 0){  
                   alert('You dont have a camera');  
                                            return;
                }else{
                    alert("cam detected");
                                            return;

                }
                tester = true;
            }catch(e){
                tester = false;
                setTimeout(test,1000);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(test,1000);



</script>

<div id="camera" style="opacity:0"></div>
```